# React Native not working

Tags: react-native

I am working on react native and building my app on android pyhsical device but it throws an error.
I have set my `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME` variabes but still not working.

This is exactly what it is returning :-

Scanning folders for symlinks in */home/harsh/Desktop/App/node_modules* (9ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (`cd android && ./gradlew installDebug`)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- **What went wrong:**
  Could not determine java version from '10.0.1'.
- **Try:**
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Your error may come from the fact that you have 2 differents jdk installed and, since react should not be used with a jdk > 9 yet, check your Java installation with java -v in order to get the version.